# designing manually SSO

Tags: jakarta-ee, single-sign-on, rmi

I have two application servers on different computers listening on www.A.com and www.B.com. 
www.A.com and www.B.com have same dbs with users.

A user U logs in www.A.com. www.A.com using rmi somehow creates a servlet context for A on www.B.com.

Then U visits www.B.com and is already logged in.

Any thould how to achieve this?

PS: Please do not recommend me any SSO solution (such as CAS). I want to solve it manually.
PS: I guess that somehow I should create a ServletContext on www.B.com and populating
with user's IP, username and password.

Comment: I think you'll run into problems. How will you know it's the same user connecting and not someone spoofing the IP address? Might be worth looking at the SAML protocol as a starting point.

Comment: 'Somehow creates a servlet context for A on B' doesn't make sense. You need to figure out how you're going to securely and unambiguously identify your clients. Clearly a cookie is going to be required. I doubt that RMI will have anything to do with it in the end.

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback. Identifying the user isn't a problem. Assume that there is a way. My problem is how to create "manually" a session context for another user that when he access my web application for the 1st time he is already logged in without giving credentials!

Comment: Session, not session context.

Comment: Have you tried cookies?  Create a cookie when User logs in to A.com. When User lands in B.com, detect the cookie, get user info from the cookie, and log him in.  This works if both A.com and B.com can read the same cookie.